# Tradingview real time processing on strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to program a strategy on TradingView. Essentially, it compares the close of the last candle with the open of the current one. If there is a difference greater than X, I want it to enter at the market price at that moment. I'm trying to use "calc_on_every_tick=true" because otherwise, the order is executed on the next candle, which doesn't work for me.

The problem is that it still enters on the next candle instead of when the condition is met.

Here's the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Mi estrategia", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)

//variable
diferencia = close [1]-open

// enter
if diferencia<-3 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit('Exit Long', from_entry='Largo', profit=close[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`process_orders_on_close`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy)

Something like this:

```
strategy("Mi estrategia", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true)
```